# Watir: "unexpected alert open" error thrown when trying to refresh page after manually closing alert

Tags: watir, selenium-chromedriver

I've created an instance of `Watir::Browser` with chrome set as the browser.

```
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
```

If I **manually** close an alert and then try to refresh the page using

```
b.refresh
```

the following error is thrown:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledAlertError: unexpected alert open
  (Session info: chrome=28.0.1500.95)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.2,platform=Windows NT 6.1 x86_64)
        from C:/ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:51:in     assert_ok'
        from C:/ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in     initialize'
        from C:/ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in     new'
        from C:/ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in     create_response'
        from C:/ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:66:in     request'
        from C:/ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in     call'
        from C:/ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:634:in     raw_execute'
        from C:/ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:612:in     execute'
        from C:/ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:210:in     refresh'
        from C:/ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/navigation.rb:38:in     refresh'
        from C:/ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.4/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:201:in     refresh'
```

When I call `b.alert.exists?` it returns `true`.

I tried looking at using `b.alert.initialize` to reset the state of the alert but it throwns an exception.

Is there a way to completely reset the state of the browser object?

Comment: same here alert not working...I tried with firefox too, not much success. b.alert.exists? b.alert.ok I tried every thing on http://watirwebdriver.com/javascript-dialogs/ but no luck you?

Answer (score 7):

I was facing this problem too:

But I am successfully get rid of it by putting it in a `begin-rescue` block.

Here is how:

```
  begin
    # put line of code which triggers alert on page
  rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledAlertError
    @browser.alert.ok 
  end
```